# turtlebot_gazebo segfaults

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I can run roslaunch `gazebo_ros empty_world.launch` with no problems. But when I run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch` something is causing gazebo to crash. Here's the output to stdout:

```
[ INFO] [1538334250.246949556]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.  
[ INFO] [1538334250.248765068]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)  
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 10070, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/gazebo-1.log].  
log file: /home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/gazebo-1*.log
```

When I try to dig in deeper by looking at the logs I don't get a whole lot more info:

```
cat /home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/* | grep ERROR
[rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2018-09-30 02:09:11,027: Traceback (most recent call last):  
[rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2018-09-30 12:04:47,260: Traceback (most recent call last):  
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-30 12:04:10,934: [gazebo-1] process has died [pid 10070, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/gazebo-1.log].  
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-30 02:09:11,070: [gazebo-1] process has died [pid 2520, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/gazebo-1.log].  
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2018-09-30 02:15:46,626: [gazebo-1] process has died [pid 4034, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/thomas/.ros/log/6a98e730-c490-11e8-a58a-7cdd90a0f479/gazebo-1.log].  
[rosout][ERROR] 2018-09-30 02:15:46,543: Unpause physics service call failed: unable to connect to service: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Oh and also

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 313, in <module>  
    sm.callSpawnService()  
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 289, in callSpawnService  
    rospy.wait_for_service('%s/unpause_physics'%(self.gazebo_namespace))  
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 159, in wait_for_service  
    raise ROSInterruptException("rospy shutdown")  
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: rospy shutdown
```

So it's dying when it tries to call the spawn service. Any help would be most appreciated. I'm really excited to get started using ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20578/turtlebot_gazebo-segfaults/) by [odellus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5736/odellus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [odellus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5736/odellus/) on 2018-09-30**:
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, no VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I upgraded to turtlebot3_gazebo and it resolved my issue.

---

Originally posted by [odellus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5736/odellus/) with karma: 16 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0